# How can I use basic tricks for improving my Julia code?

Tags: performance, julia

I'm relatively new with Julia and I'm currently using version 1.0. I have a code that is intendend to produce a sequence of integers, based on an input matrix. The code takes 3 hours to run on my machine (i5, dual core, 16GB ram), using 16% of CPU and 3% of memory. Is there any basic tips I can learn and apply to optimize my code in Julia to improve its performance? Does indentation have an effect on performance? Is there a package that can track my code and suggest improvements? I provide my code below. The code includes a R code that generates data to which the Julia code is applicable. If an error occurs during the R code, it's just a lack of achievement during simulations and it must be run again until simulation is complete.

```
using Distances
using RCall
using Distributions
using BSON: @save, @load
using StatsBase
using LinearAlgebra

R"simul<-function(m){
  comb<-expand.grid(c(0.01,0.2,0.4),
                c(sample(2:7,1),sample(8:12,1),sample(13:20,1)),
                c(sample(2:5,1),sample(6:10,1),sample(11:20,1)),
                c(150,500,1500))
gener<-function(i){
maxoverlap<-comb[i,1]
nbvar<-comb[i,2]
nbclass<-comb[i,3]
propmix<-runif(1,0.001,1/nbclass)
Q<-MixSim(MaxOmega = maxoverlap, K = nbclass, p = nbvar,PiLow = propmix,resN = 1000)
A <- simdataset(n = comb[i,4], Pi = Q$Pi, Mu = Q$Mu, S = Q$S)
results<-list(Q,A)
return(results)
}
donnees<-sapply(1:nrow(comb),gener)
}
library(MixSim)
donneesimul=simul(1)"
@rget donneesimul

function pointsdpp(t)
 datasim=donneesimul[2,t][:X]

 Eucldist=pairwise(Euclidean(),transpose(datasim))
 D=maximum(Eucldist.^2)
 sigma2hat=mean(((Eucldist.^2)./D)[tril!(trues(size((Eucldist.^2)./D)),-1)])
 L=exp.(-(Eucldist.^2/D)/(2*sigma2hat))

 eigenv=eigvals(L)
 prob=eigenv./(eigenv.+1)
 eigenvectors=eigvecs(L)
function sampledpp(m)
u=rand(size(L,1))
V=eigenvectors[:,findall(u.<=prob)]
k=size(V,2)
Y=zeros(Int64,k)
for i=k:-1:1
P=sum(V.^2,dims=2)
Pri=P / sum(P)
Cumpri=cumsum(Pri,dims=1)
u=rand()
Y[i]=findfirst(u.<=Cumpri)[1]
if i==1 break end
j=findfirst(V[Y[i],:].!=0)
Vj=V[:,j]
V=V[:,deleteat!(collect(1:1:size(V,2)),j)]
V=V-repeat(Vj,1,size(V,2)).*repeat(transpose(V[Y[i],:]/Vj[Y[i]]),size(V,1))

for a = 1:i-1
    for b = 1:a-1
      V[:,a] = V[:,a] - transpose(V[:,a])*V[:,b]*V[:,b]
    end
    V[:,a] = V[:,a] / norm(V[:,a])
end
end
Y=sort(Y)
return(Y)
end

m=collect(1:1000)
sampleY_repet=map(sampledpp,m)
end
w=collect(1:1:81)
echantdpp=map(pointsdpp,w)
@save "echantdppdatasim1.bson" echantdpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues to be considered when evaluating Julia performance. While the code you provided is far beyond MWE (minimal working example) and is not reproducible neither. 
However, here are some general guidelines:

1. Take some time to read carefully the [Julia performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html) and apply them
2. Since you process some arrays your code will likely benefit from the `@simd` macro. Using array views is also very often a low-hanging-fruit for codes such as yours.
3. You use 16% of CPU power (likely you have 8 cores and your program uses just one). Consider using either multi-threading or multiprocessing - your program will run many times faster
4. For some scenario you might consider using GPU computing with Flux.jl
5. Consider moving your multi-core computation to the cloud (Julia scaling on AWS EC2 instances works fantastic)

Since each of those topics is a big area on its own work step-by-step on your code and ask questions to get help.

Comment: Thank you! It was precisely what I was looking for! These types of tips!

Comment: I included a R code that simulates a database to which the Julia code is applicable. The idea is to apply the Julia function to all the 81 columns of the matrix generated by R.